# Header margin is pushing div with background image

Tags: html, css, margins

I want to set a margin of 100px between the header and .content-container. Every time I set the margin, either on the header or .content-container, the background image is pushed as well. Maybe it's connected to the position attributes for the .content-wrap and header selectors, but I'm not sure. I'm still new to frontend dev, so I'm not sure where the problem could be.

```css
html, body, header, h1, h2, h3, div, figure, figcaption, img, p, a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sticky-footer-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;

/*Equal to height of footer*/
margin-bottom: -200px;
}

.content-wrap {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: -10;
}

.content-wrap::after {
content: "";
background: #5F5449 url(http://margraonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/pretty-coffee-beans.jpeg);
opacity: 0.5;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}

header {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
background: #291711;
}

header img {
display: block;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
float: left;
}

header h1 {
color: #EEF0F2;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}

header nav {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

header nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #D1BEB0;
padding-right: 15px;
font-size: 20px;
}

a:nth-child(5) {
padding-right: 55px;
}

a:hover {
color: #938BA1;
}

#active-link {
color: #938BA1;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.content-container {
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 300px;
width: 60%;
background-color: #D9C9BE;
border: 2px solid #291711; 
}

.content-container h2 {
font-size: 36px;
color: #4E453C;
text-decoration: underline;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 0;
} 

.content-container h3 {
font-size: 26px;
color: #3C2C26;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

figure {
display: block;
border: 1px solid #3C2C26;
background-color: #FFFCF3;
height: 300px;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

figure img {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

figcaption, p {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

blockquote {
position: relative;
font-size: 18px;
}

footer, push {
height: 200px;
}

footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #291711;
text-align: center;
}

footer nav a {
float: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
color: #D1BEB0;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-weight: lighter;
padding-right: 15px;
}

#top-row {
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#bottom-row {
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

footer p {
color: #D1BEB0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bloc Frontend Formations Part 1</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="sticky-footer-wrapper">
  
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v6FOpf0.png" title="source: imgur.com" />
    <h1>Specialty Coffee Company</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About SCC</a>
      <a id="active-link" href="#">Rare Coffees</a>
      <a href="#">Store</a>
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Content Wrap -->
  <div class="content-wrap">
    
    <!-- Content Container -->
    <section class="content-container">
      <h2>Rare Coffees</h2>
      <h3>Kopi Luwak</h3>
        <figure>
          <img src="https://www.indoneo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luwak_coffee_for_sale.jpg" alt="Kopi Luwak Coffee">
          <figcaption><i>Kopi luwak for sale in Indonesia.</i></figcaption>
        </figure>  
      <blockquote>"It’s the world’s most expensive coffee, and it’s made from poop. Or rather, it’s made from coffee beans that are partially digested and then pooped out by the civet, a catlike creature. A cup of kopi luwak, as it’s known, can sell for as much as $80 in the United States."</blockquote>
     <p><cite>The Disturbing Secret Behind the World’s Most Expensive Coffee</cite> by Rachael Bale. <a href="http://www.nationalgeographic.com/">National Geographic</a>. <time>April 29, 2016</time></p>

    <!-- End Content Container -->
    </section>

  <!-- End Content Wrap -->
  </div>
  
  <!-- Push for Sticky Footer -->
  <div class="push"></div>

  <!-- End Sticky Footer Wrapper -->
  </div>

  <footer>
    <nav id="top-row">
      <a href="#">Locations</a>
      <a href="#">Press</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
      <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </nav>
    <nav id="bottom-row">
      <a href="#">Sustainability</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <p>Speciality Coffee Company, Torokv&eacutesz &uacutet 95-97, Budapest</p> 
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` of 100px.

**Reason:** Margin increase the space between elements, it doesn't actually increase the elements dimensions, whereas padding increases the space between the element edge and the content, which is what is needed in the current scenario!

```css
html, body, header, h1, h2, h3, div, figure, figcaption, img, p, a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sticky-footer-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;

/*Equal to height of footer*/
margin-bottom: -200px;
}

.content-wrap {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: -10;
}

.content-wrap::after {
content: "";
background: #5F5449 url(http://margraonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/pretty-coffee-beans.jpeg);
opacity: 0.5;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}

header {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
background: #291711;
}

header img {
display: block;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
float: left;
}

header h1 {
color: #EEF0F2;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}

header nav {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

header nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #D1BEB0;
padding-right: 15px;
font-size: 20px;
}

a:nth-child(5) {
padding-right: 55px;
}

a:hover {
color: #938BA1;
}

#active-link {
color: #938BA1;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.content-container {
padding-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 300px;
width: 60%;
background-color: #D9C9BE;
border: 2px solid #291711; 
}

.content-container h2 {
font-size: 36px;
color: #4E453C;
text-decoration: underline;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 0;
} 

.content-container h3 {
font-size: 26px;
color: #3C2C26;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

figure {
display: block;
border: 1px solid #3C2C26;
background-color: #FFFCF3;
height: 300px;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

figure img {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

figcaption, p {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

blockquote {
position: relative;
font-size: 18px;
}

footer, push {
height: 200px;
}

footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #291711;
text-align: center;
}

footer nav a {
float: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
color: #D1BEB0;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-weight: lighter;
padding-right: 15px;
}

#top-row {
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#bottom-row {
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

footer p {
color: #D1BEB0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bloc Frontend Formations Part 1</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="sticky-footer-wrapper">
  
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v6FOpf0.png" title="source: imgur.com" />
    <h1>Specialty Coffee Company</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About SCC</a>
      <a id="active-link" href="#">Rare Coffees</a>
      <a href="#">Store</a>
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Content Wrap -->
  <div class="content-wrap">
    
    <!-- Content Container -->
    <section class="content-container">
      <h2>Rare Coffees</h2>
      <h3>Kopi Luwak</h3>
        <figure>
          <img src="https://www.indoneo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luwak_coffee_for_sale.jpg" alt="Kopi Luwak Coffee">
          <figcaption><i>Kopi luwak for sale in Indonesia.</i></figcaption>
        </figure>  
      <blockquote>"It’s the world’s most expensive coffee, and it’s made from poop. Or rather, it’s made from coffee beans that are partially digested and then pooped out by the civet, a catlike creature. A cup of kopi luwak, as it’s known, can sell for as much as $80 in the United States."</blockquote>
     <p><cite>The Disturbing Secret Behind the World’s Most Expensive Coffee</cite> by Rachael Bale. <a href="http://www.nationalgeographic.com/">National Geographic</a>. <time>April 29, 2016</time></p>

    <!-- End Content Container -->
    </section>

  <!-- End Content Wrap -->
  </div>
  
  <!-- Push for Sticky Footer -->
  <div class="push"></div>

  <!-- End Sticky Footer Wrapper -->
  </div>

  <footer>
    <nav id="top-row">
      <a href="#">Locations</a>
      <a href="#">Press</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
      <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </nav>
    <nav id="bottom-row">
      <a href="#">Sustainability</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <p>Speciality Coffee Company, Torokv&eacutesz &uacutet 95-97, Budapest</p> 
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct! I needed to add padding instead of margin to .content-container. Thanks!